# How to traverse a json tree file and remove nodes?

Tags: javascript, json, traversal

I'm trying to traverse through a json file (a tree) and given a specific node, I want to keep THAT node and all its children. I have tried writing some javascript code that does this, but I get an error "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded". Here's the code I use:

```
function removeNodes(tree){
    //Check if root node contains any children.
    if(tree["children"]){
        var children = tree["children"];
        //Loop through all children and delete their everything further down in their hierarchy.
        for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            var node = children[i];

            var grandChildren = node["children"];
            if(grandChildren){  
                grandChildren.splice(i,1);
                i--;
            }

            removeNodes(node);
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? And how can I traverse my json file properly. To explain once more:
Given a root node ("tree" in this case), I want to keep the root node and all it's children, but remove anything else below in the hiercharchy.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't use the `tree` parameter. Your function just checks one specific value and then it calls itself and then checks the same value again.

Comment: I fixed that, but I'm still looping till infinity it seems. I don't understand why.

Comment: How big is the tree? I know javascript lacks proper tail calls but it seems unlikely that you'd be blowing your stack unless the tree is __very__ large or as you've suggested its recursing infinitely

Comment: It seems that when you do i-- you are looping through the same node over and over causing stackoverflow.

Comment: @specialscope Yes, I think so too, but I only do "i--" if a node has a grandchild, so I don't understand why it won't stop at some point.

Comment: @JaredSmith The tree is decently big I guess. I don't know how many nodes there are exactly but here's a picture where you can sort of see the quantity: http://puu.sh/cyMB9/e7182af0d8.png

Comment: Assume you hit grandchildren @i=1, i-- sets i=0, makes recursive call, and when you come back to the loop loop will continue from i=1 again. Do you absolutely need to use i--. To achieve your goal though, you need to find your target node and just return the node, that will give you what you want.

Comment: in-order: recur left, visit node, recur right

Answer (score 0):

```
function removeNodes(tree, desiredNode){      

    //check if node is one we want        
    if (tree == desiredNode) {
        return tree;
    }

    //Check if root node contains any children.
    if(tree && tree.children){
        var children = tree.children;

        //Loop through all children and delete their everything further down in their hierarchy.
        for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            var node = removeNodes(children[i], desiredNode);

            if (node == desiredNode) {
                return node;
            } 
        }
    }
    return false; //if no match found
}

var foo = removeNodes(tree, someNodeToKeep);
if (foo) {
    var parent = tree.parentNode;
    parent.removeChild(tree);
    parent.appendChild(foo);  //parent now contains only that node and children
}
```

Please note that like any recursive function, this can blow the stack on languages without proper tail calls, but unless you're using this to search a **large** data structure it should be fine.